# How does Spark know where the Yarn Resource Manager is running when not using spark-submit.sh?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am quite new to Spark and I am trying to start a Spark job from inside my application (without using spark-submit.sh) in yarn-cluster mode and I am trying to figure out how the job gets to know where the Yarn ResourceManager is running. 
I have done

```
SparkConf sConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-cluster").set("spark.driver.memory", "10g");
```

But what I am not able to configure is the location of the Yarn ResourceManager. Any ideas on how I go about doing it? I have a clustered setup where the Yarn RM does not run on the same machine as the application.

Answer (score 2):

The properties can be found in `yarn-site.xml` either located in your `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` or `YARN_CONF_DIR` environment variables, which are either set at the OS level, or in `spark-env.sh`.

In a non-HA deployment, you are looking for `yarn.resourcemanager.address`

Answer (score 0):

Look into Spark Launcher API - [org.apache.spark.launcher Java Doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html) 

Or read about it here - [SparkLauncher — Launching Spark Applications](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-SparkLauncher.html)

Comment: I understand that the spark-submit script does quite a lot like create the classpaths on the worker nodes etc. But the Spark API has support to set the classpaths too though it is a bit tedious. But what I could not find was how to set the location of the Yarn cluster. Will setting the HADOOP_CONF_DIR environment variable work?

Comment: Documentation states that Spark will know about YARN ResourceManager from `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` or `YARN_CONF_DIR` (e.g. yarn-site.xml).
 More info on Spark docs - [Running Spark on YARN](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)